# Running old Windows game with 2 CDs on Mac OS X

Tags: windows, macos, wine, emulation

There is an old Windows game that comes on 2 CDs. It works such that when you reach a certain point in the game, it will prompt you to insert the second CD to continue.

I have a friend who would like to play this game on their MacBook which is running Mac OS X. I have the 2 CDs as .iso files, and was considering using [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) to emulate the game, but I'm not sure how I would emulate both CDs. Should I extract both the CD's contents to a folder and then try and play the game? I haven't really used Wine for anything like this before so it would be great if someone could give me an idea how to accomplish this. Thanks!

Comment: On Windows, I would mount the first ISO and then switch to the second when the game requests it (they usually look for the second CD in the same drive). Not sure how OS X/WINE would affect this, though.

Comment: I'd mount the ISOs to separate folders, and map these folders to drives. If it still insists for the second CD in the same drive, then you can do a force unmount of the first ISO & mount the second

Comment: And is it possible to do this with Wine?

Comment: @DanieL should be possible, but I don't have OSX

Comment: Have you considered using VirtualBox (free) or VMware Fusion to virtualize a full Windows system? You probably also have an old Windows license lying around...

Comment: @DanielBeck - I would considering an old game to be something that was released 8 years ago.  Either product would have a problem running a game from 2004.

Comment: @Ramhound 3D Mark 05 score of 5200 in Windows 8 Consumer Preview with VMware Fusion on a 2010 Macbook Pro with i7. [Link](http://3dmark.com/3dm05/5447231;jsessionid=ftjngmcaqlm0nw31c3jek3md). Doesn't look too bad. Downloading the Doom 3 trial (2004 game) right now...

Comment: @Ramhound [2004 video card benchmark](http://www.xbitlabs.com/articles/graphics/display/2004-27gpu2_40.html#sect0). So my virtual Windows effectively has a higher-end 2004 graphics card.